# Eclipse Plugins - How to find the PreferenceStore corresponding to a .pref file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to modify a default preference value that was set by another plugin. I have found the .pref file where the preference is stored. Is there a way to tell which PreferenceStore was the one that wrote the preference into the disk? If so, how can its instance be retrieved?

The file is called org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs, if that helps. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The file name of the .prefs file is the plugin id that owns the preferences.

You can access these preferences using:

```java
IPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, id);
```

in your case `id` would be `"org.eclipse.ui.editors"`

Note: The contents of the preferences files are not part of the Eclipse API and may change from release to release. There may be a better way to find what you want to know.